# ERROR TypeError: c.show is not a function, when we double click the diagram or node

Tags: javascript, typescript, gojs

I'm facing an issue with gojs diagram, when double clicked on it, to edit the node name.I recently have upgraded my gojs version from v1.7.14 to v2.2.17.
Here is the error stack trace for the same

```
core.mjs:8453 ERROR TypeError: c.show is not a function
at Og.doActivate (go-module.js:522:434)
at La.doMouseUp (go-module.js:314:273)
at Q.doMouseUp (go-module.js:616:118)
at a.bk (go-module.js:611:261)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423:31)
at core.mjs:23924:55
at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:23924:36)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422:60)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:24225:33)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422:60)
```

I recently have upgraded my gojs version from v1.7.14 to v2.2.17, but the double click functionality on the node/diagram broke.
Any idea on this?
It would be of great help.
TIA

Comment: I believe the questions has been downvoted because it is somewhat vague. More [code/details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused in GoJS v2.0 by the removal of **HTMLElement**s as permitted values for properties such as **GraphObject.toolTip** and **GraphObject.contextMenu**.

That functionality has been replaced by the GoJS **HTMLInfo** class to provide a standardized way of interacting with HTMLElements.  Please read https://gojs.net/latest/intro/HTMLInteraction.html#HTMLInfoClass and https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/HTMLInfo.html.

So you will need to modify your code to wrap an **HTMLInfo** around your use of an **HTMLElement**.

Comment: Yep that's correct. Thanks for helping me out!